# How to call a function based on list entry?

Tags: python, stack, sandbox

I'm currently working on an experiment where I'm implementing an interpreter for an old in-game scripting language. It's a forth based language, so I figure it would be fairly easy to just have the instructions (once verified and santized) put into a big list.

Once I've got the code in a list, I am trying to iterate through the entire program in a for loop that processes the instructions one at a time. Certain items, like strings, could be placed onto a variable that holds the current stack, which is easy enough. But where I'm stuck is making commands happen.

I have a big list of functions that are valid and I'd like it to where if any instruction matches them, it calls the associated function.

So, for example, if I had:

```
    "Hello, world!" notify
```

...the code would check for notify in a list and then execute the notify function. The bottom line is: How do I translate a string into a function name?

Comment: So you want `"Hello, world!" notify` to behave like `notify("Hello, world!")`?

Comment: Well, it would actually call the notify function, which would take the stack variable and pop the required items off it to do the notification, but more or less, yes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with regex use in Python but it looks like you'll have to match the string to everything in the quotation marks (exclusively) and make sure you check for escaped quotation marks. Then you would use a capture group to determine which function to call. Parsing can always be cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could keep a dictionary of functions the code can call, and then do a look up when you need to:

```
def notify(s):
    print(s)

d = {"notify": notify}

d["notify"]("Hello, world!")
```

Comment: Won't that just call the notify function and place its result in the value of that dictionary?

Comment: Functions in python are first class objects, `notify` is just the name bound to that function (try the code, it runs as is).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through **locals** which is a dictionary with th current local symbol table:

```
locals()["notify"]()
```

or though **globals** which returns a dictionary with the symbol table of globals:

```
 globals()["notify"]()
```

You can give arguments too e.g.:

```
locals()["notify"]("Hello, world!")
```

or

```
globals()["notify"]("Hello, world!")
```

Comment: Can I create my own symbol table? I don't want the user to be able to run just any command.

Comment: `locals()` and `globals()` return dictionaries, so you can make your own instead.

Comment: yes @strcat is right. You can use this interface: http://docs.python.org/library/symtable.html#module-symtable
 to examine these symbol tables.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import re
class LangLib(object):
    pattern = re.compile(r'"(.*?)" (.*)')
    def run_line(self, line):
        arg, command = re.match(LangLib.pattern, line).groups()
        return getattr(self, command)(arg)
    def notify(self, arg):
        print arg
```

Then your engine code would be:

```
parser = LangLib()
for line in program_lines:
    parser.run_line(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `dict` called `commands` that maps names to functions, you can do it like this:

```
def my_notify_function():
    print(stack.pop)

commands = {'notify': my_notify_function, ...}

for item in program:
    if item in commands:
        commands[item]()
    else:
        stack.push(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary of function names and some tags.

I have tried it several times before, it works really well.